# EC2- connecting to an independently installed SQL Server Express

Tags: amazon-ec2, sql-server-2014-express

PLEASE NOTE: This is not an RDS or a prepackaged EC2 with SQL Server solution. I installed an express copy independently after setting up the EC2 instance.

I am evaluating a free tier instance of AWS EC2. Several months in, I decided to install SQL Server 2014 express on the instance on my own. However I cannot connect to the SQL Server instance via SSMS from another server box local to us.

The following is a checklist of what I have done so far:

- SQL Server Configuration Manager

  - Configured to run SQL Browser
  - Enabled TCP on the SQL Server instance
- Windows Firewall

  - Created an inbound rule to allow communication on TCP port 1433 and 1434
  - Created an inbound rule to allow communication on UDP port 1434
- AWS security group of EC2 instance where SQL Instance resides

  - Mirrored the rules above in the Windows firewall for inbound traffic from the local server I'm trying to access the EC2 instance from
  - Successfully tested if RDP and ICMP work on the instance

I believe my issue lies in the how I am referring to the SQL instance:

```
ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com\INSTANCE_NAME
```

I've also noticed that when I log in on the EC2 instance's copy of SSMS, there is a two part name like so:

```
WIN#########\INSTANCE_NAME
```

Please help as I feel I've exhausted all options. This shouldn't be that impossible.

Comment: have you checked the Security Group this instance is using?  maybe you need to add another rule for another port number (for SSMS).

Comment: It is supposed to run on 1433 or 1434.  I have tried both ports but none of them seem to work.  Should the server name be "IP\ServerName"?  Is that the right way to refer to this sql instance residing on an AWS instance, because I know RDS works very differently.

Comment: I have even adjusted the IP3 address under TCP/IP properties of the instance to specifically listen on port 1433 and still nothing.  Am I naming the instance correctly?